ImportRange Query Formatted Incorrectly
I have a spreadsheet that I want to pull data from another spreadsheet.
This is my formula:
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14lj6yPp8h9U1JAEA4dz-uROaQgZxy60NjXniHOFUeAU/edit#gid=0", "TRANSACTIONS!B6:P9999"), "select Col2, Col3, Col13, Col14, Col15, Col16 where Col16='EV' and Col2>=date '"&to_text("2024-04-01")&"' AND Col2<date '"&to_text("2024-05-01")&"'", 0)
This is the error I am receiving:

Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col16

What am I doing wrong?

The range B6:P9999 has 15 columns. This explains the error.
In other words, B is Col1, C is Col2, and so on. P is Col15.

Thank you! I made the assumption, obviously, that the columns referred to the entire sheet, not the imported range.  Doh!  Thanks for the clarification.

@Salt_Tea you've asked a few questions that have received answers consider accepting and or upvoting if they solved your problem. See what can I do when someone answers my question?
